# Linux - How to Configure SFTP server along with Local Git Repository

Tags: git, unix, hosting, sftp

Currently I am configuring both SFTP and Local git repository on same server. There will be 2 types of groups: `sftp-users` & `git-users`. I have restricted `sftp-usres` only to their `home` directories using `ChrootDirectory %h`. Now when I allow just `sftp-users` using SFTP(to download/view files), then it doesn't allow `git-users`to login through putty or to clone projects on client side.

So what is the best way to configure both type of group in same server, so that `git-users` are unable to view code repositories through FTP clients?? Any suggestion will be highly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say you're doing this wrong with regard to Git.

Instead of implementing real system logins for SSH access
(what you call "login through putty"),
it's advised to create a single "virtual" user
(typically called `git`)
and have all Git users use that single user
to log into the system using SSH —
while at the same time having certain means
to distinguish different users based on their *SSH keys.*

Such distinguishing is typically implemented using
[`gitolite`](https://gitolite.com)
(usually that's just `apt install gitolite`).

The idea is that each distinct Git user has their own
SSH key, and that virtual system user `git` on the server
has something provided by `gitolite` set as its login shell.
Each Git user logs in as `git@server` but uses its own SSH key
for authentication. After logging the user in, the SSH server
calls `gitolite`, and it uses its own mapping of users' keys
to individual users, *which are purely virtual* in the sense
they do not have accounts on the server.

This allows you to fully decouple Git hosting from SFTP hosting.

Another possible solution is to serve Git repositories via HTTP
rather than SSH.  You could then use any of the HTTP server's means
of authenticating your users which, again, would allow decoupling
of the databases of the Git users and SFTP users.
(But they could use the same authentication backend, say, PAM,
if needed — see [this](http://icephoenix.us/linuxunix/apache-and-http-authentication-with-pam/) for one example.)

---

As an aside, [your question if offtopic on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic);
please use [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/git+ssh) for the questions like yours
(dedicated to software configuration / administration problems).